# Hash holding string arrays doesn't read individual strings in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I'm trying to make an array that collects individual strings from other arrays and then creates a hash that counts how many of each string is contained in `estimate.bottom`. Bottom `belongs_to` Estimate.

My problem is that it doesn't currently read the individual strings, but the array as a whole.  So if the bottoms are `["a", "b"]` , `["a"]` , and `["b"]` the hash bottom_count will be `{["a"]=>1, ["b"]=>1, ["a", "b"]=>1}` instead of `{["a"]=>2, ["b"]=>2}`

```
@in_bottom = []
@estimates.each do |est|
  @in_bottom << est.bottom 
end
@bottom_count = Hash.new(0)
@in_bottom.each { |in_bottom| @bottom_count[in_bottom] += 1 }
```

How can I make the method iterate through the individual strings and make `bottom_count` work correctly?

Comment: Replace `@in_bottom << est.bottom` with `@in_bottom << est.bottom.flatten`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- @in_bottom.each { |in_bottom| @bottom_count[in_bottom] += 1 }
+ @in_bottom.flatten.each { |in_bottom| @bottom_count[in_bottom] += 1 }
```

See [Documentation Array flatten method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-flatten)